# ajax json adding trailing colon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
var mydata = {
    "one": {
        "brand": "acer",
        "cost": "212132"
    }
}


$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(mydata)
    });
```

Above code is adding a colon to the data when i view the form send data in chrome dev tools. Is there anything wrong with the request?

Comment: you didn't close the quote in `url: 'http://localhost,`. It should be `url: 'http://localhost',`

Comment: you missed single quote after url

Comment: sorry that's not the problem, i missed in paste

Comment: do you want to send the data as parameters or as request body

Comment: if you want to send the data as parameters then `data: mydata`

Comment: Do you mean that you see a trailing `:` in `Network > Headers > Form Data` (`{"one":{"brand":"acer","cost":"212132"}}:`) if so thats what I also see. It is because you send it as _plain data_ - passing it with `data: JSON.stringify(mydata)`  - and not with `data: mydata`, but it does not mean that the colon is really send to the server.

Comment: could be, cause no identifier is send(i mean variable name, like login="some login"); you can try {data: JSON.stringify(mydata)}

Answer (score 8):

You are viewing application/x-www-form-urlencoded parsed data. So Chrome is trying to establish key value pairs. Click "view source" near the "Form Data" heading in the network tab view. You will see your JSON without the colon.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes sense. I thought I was going mad!

Answer (score 2):

Was the same for me. I did not see the colon when viewing source. BUT it did not work.
My solution was to add the missing `contentType`

```
$.ajax({
        url: `url`,
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
```